# How to Add Animations to a Component in Angular where the template is based on ngTemplate

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

The template for this component is like this

```
<ng-template #primary @fading><ng-content select="[primary]"></ng-content></ng-template> // gives error
<ng-template #secondary> <ng-content select="[secondary]"></ng-content></ng-template>


<ng-container *ngIf="(mode | async)=== mode_layout_100_0">
  <div class="h-100">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="primary"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="(mode | async)=== mode_layout_0_100">
  <div class="h-100">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="secondary"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="(mode | async)=== mode_layout_33_66">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row h-100 split-view" @fading> // dosent work 
    <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block col-lg-4 p-0">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="primary"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 p-0 view-seperator">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="secondary"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="(mode | async)=== mode_layout_66_33">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row h-100 split-view">
    <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="primary"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-0 view-seperator">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="secondary"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

It acts as Manager which splits the view depending upon what we want primary or secondary or a mix of both and the layout of 33 % to 66 %.

I have added the following metadata to the decorator

```
animations: [
    trigger('fading', [
      transition(':enter', animate('800ms ease-out')),
      transition(':leave', animate('800ms ease-in')),
    ])
  ]
```

What i am trying to achieve is when ever the view changes from mode from Primary to secondary incase of nested use of this component . There whould be a smooth animation of ease in and out .

How do i add the animate tag I tried adding to the `ng-template` it gives an error and if i add to each div it dosent work .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible using **ng-template** at least for Angular 6 (and 7). This Angular directive is managed internally by it, so I haven't found anything by a thorough search.

What I've used to overcome this situation is adding a variable inside the component code and use in the component HTML markup with a conditional ***ngIf** directive evaluating this. For cases of using rxjs **Observable**, subscribe to it and then change the **loading** value to *true*. Just don't forget to add your animation properly to the HTML divs you want to animate.

### my.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loading" @animation>
...
</div>
<div *ngIf="!loading" @animation>
...
</div>
```

### my.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'],
  animations: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean = true;
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.config$.subscribe(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I too want to animate contents of an `<ng-template>`, but I guess is not possible that way ...

Comment: Yep, if I found something I'll update my answer. But for now this is the only way I know how to do this.